# Populate table view after NSPredicate

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, nsfetchrequest

I have a search bar with core data and I've an issue.

When I search something the NSPredicate show the results on playground but I cannot reload the table view and them doesn't show anything.

I would like to know if I can reload the table with this code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    var person = people[indexPath.row]
    if searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        person = filteredPeople[indexPath.row]
    }
    cell.textLabel?.text = person.value(forKeyPath: "name") as? String
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.disclosureIndicator
     return cell
}
```

or I need to create a fetchResultsController.

filteredPeople is obtain after fetchRequest:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Person")
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[c] %@",searchController.searchBar.text!)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    do {
        let filteredPeople = try! managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Person]
        for result in filteredPeople as [Person] {
            print("\(result.name!)")
        }
    }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

All the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common mistake.

You are declaring a **local variable** with the `let` keyword which is not the same object as the data source array.

Remove `let`

```
filteredPeople = try! managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Person]
```